# Lying Over Theorem + Is $\mathbf{C}[x] \hookrightarrow \mathbf{C}[x, y]/(xy-1)$ an integral extension?

Tags: commutative-algebra, integral-extensions

I am confused about something.

When introducing the Lying Over Theorem -- namely, that if $f \colon R \subset S$ is an integral extension then $f^* \colon \mathrm{Spec}(S) \to \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is a surjection -- my professor said that the intuition ''$X \to Y$ is a 'cover' implies it is a surjection'' is not always true.

His example was $\mathbf{C}^* \hookrightarrow \mathbf{C}$ and the induced map $\mathbf{C}[x] \hookrightarrow \mathbf{C}[x, y]/(xy - 1)$, where you visualize $\mathbf{C}^*$ as the hyperbola $xy = 1$ and see that its projection onto the $x$-axis is not surjective.  But is it not true that $\mathbf{C}[x] \hookrightarrow \mathbf{C}[x, y]/(xy-1)$ is integral?  Since $y$ satisfies the polynomial $xt - 1 \in \mathbf{C}[x][t]$ and the ring is finitely generated by $y$ over $\mathbf{C}[x]$ [Incorrect, see comments]?  So why doesn't this violate what the Lying Over Theorem is trying to say?

Does anyone see what my professor meant and/or where I'm confused?  I apologize for the hazy question.

Comment: To be integral, an element must satisfy a **monic** polynomial, i.e., with leading coefficient $1$.  $xt - 1$ is not monic.

Comment: I see what you mean.  Also, I see I was wrong to say the ring is finitely generated by $y$ as a $\mathbf{C}[x]$ module.  It is finitely generated as a ring, but not a module.  Is that correct?

Comment: At least, it could be finitely generated as a $\mathbf{C}[x]$-module, but it is not obviously so...and I'm guessing that it isn't, since this was intended by my professor as a nonexample for the Lying Over Theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you state in the comments, $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy-1)$ is finitely generated as a $\mathbb{C}[x]$-algebra, but not as a $\mathbb{C}[x]$-module.  (Recall that, given an extension of rings $A \subseteq B$, one can show that $\alpha \in B$ is integral over $A$ iff $A[\alpha]$ is finitely generated as an $A$-module.)  Note that $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(xy-1) \cong \mathbb{C}[x,1/x]$ so every element is of the form $f(x)/x^e$ for some $f \in \mathbb{C}[x]$.

For contradiction, assume $\mathbb{C}[x,1/x]$ is generated by $\frac{f_1(x)}{x^{e_1}}, \ldots, \frac{f_r(x)}{x^{e_r}}$ as a $\mathbb{C}[x]$-module.  Choose $m > \max\{e_1, \ldots, e_r\}$.  Then
$$
\frac{1}{x^m} = a_1(x) \frac{f_1(x)}{x^{e_1}} + \cdots + a_r(x) \frac{f_r(x)}{x^{e_r}}
$$
for some $a_i(x) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$.  Then
$$
1 = x^{m-e_1}a_1(x) f_1(x) + \cdots + x^{m-e_r} a_r(x) f_r(x)
$$
and since $m > e_i$ for all $i$, substituting $x = 0$ yields $1 = 0$, contradiction.

Comment: I am sorry for the delayed response, it is inexcusable.  Thank you for your clear answer.